# How to format web service response to be read by Perl?

Tags: php, web-services, perl, httpresponse

I'm using Perl to request some information (plain text) from a web service I built. When accessing using the browser, the info is shown perfectly. However, I'm new to handle responses using Perl. I do some database operations successfully, and my problem comes handling the response in Perl, not PHP.

How do I must encode or format the response in order to handle it successfully and output the same plain text in Perl?

EDIT:

Key points to take into consideration

- I'm working with CakePHP 2.x (stable).
- The ***$response->content*** brings the whole HTML file (including JavaScript and the whole package). I just want to show the plain text in the Perl script.
- The Perl script fails when checking ***$response->is_success*** and goes straight to ***print "something went wrong";***.

My php script runs well

PHP code:

```
<?php
$this->layout = 'ajax';
$this->autoRender = false;
// Some database handling here with no problem...
echo "Plain text with info from database";
?>
```

Perl code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
require LWP::UserAgent;
require HTTP::Request;
my $request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
my $userAgent = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$userAgent->timeout(3);
$userAgent->env_proxy;
my $response = $userAgent->request($request);
if ($response->is_success) {
    print "Success!\n";
    #should print plain text AS IS
}
else {
    print "something went wrong...\n";
    die $response->status_line;
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? Do you want to know how to extract data from the content fetched from the web?

Comment: Yes. I put additional information to help you, guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So after it prints `something went wrong...` what is the status info it should be outputting as it dies? Also, I assume you are actually setting `$url` in your real code.

Comment: After debugging line by line, the problem went down to assigning a higher value for timeout (#facepalm for myself here). Thank you, all guys.

Answer (score 1):

After checking `$response->is_success`, you ought to be able to just take the return value of

```
$response->decoded_content
```

and process it however you see fit.